# Getting empty response, If blob field is there [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have beem retrieving the data from mysqli db by php.

```
$query = "SELECT id, parentId, firstName, middleName, lastName, mobileNumber, photo FROM person WHERE orgId='".$orgId."' ";

$sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$data=array();
        if($rows_count!=0){
            while ($rows_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                var_dump($rows_fetch);
                $info = $rows_fetch;    
                array_push($data, $info);
                $isSuccessful = true;
                $code = 200;
            }
        }else{
            $isSuccessful = true;
            $code = 202;
        }

        $response = array("resp"=>$data, "code"=>$code, "isSuccessful"=>$isSuccessful);
```

If blob field is empty, I am getting response. If blob is there, I am getting empty response

Comment: check this howto deal with BLOB data:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643242/display-blob-data-php

Comment: I want photo along with text data. Problem arising during the json_encode

Comment: what is `$contacts`??  i think it would be `json_encode($response);`

Comment: check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323185/returning-a-blob-with-json

Comment: It is response from class.

Comment: so why not you post your whole code??

Comment: I got answer from @anantkumarsingh. I will post my answer

Comment: great to hear that you got your solution

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($rows_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                //var_dump($rows_fetch);
                $info = $rows_fetch;    
                $info['photo'] = base64_encode($rows_fetch['photo']);
                array_push($data, $info);
                $isSuccessful = true;
                $code = 200;
            }
```

I have changing blob to base64 code.